# Why doesn't my .csv preserve embedded carriage returns/line feeds?

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, csv, import-from-excel

I have a .csv. I have column that is being uploaded to an 'ntext(null)' field type in SQL Server 2008 (Express). Within this column there can be data with free text with embedded char(10) and char(13)'s. In the .csv these cells are protected with " ". I BULK_INSERT the data and the column is not preserving the carriage returns or line feeds. Bummer.

God knows how but somehow in Excel on only a couple of cells I managed to get the cell to display the ascii line break (small box with ?) as well as actually visibly break at that point (as opposed to show it all on one line with the small boxes). When I upload these columns it is fine!

Any ideas on either why my upload is not preserving the line breaks and/or how to get all my cells in Excel for this column to display the line break and show the text breaking at that point?

Comment: Can you show your BULK INSERT statement?

Comment: BEGIN TRAN SAJ
 BULK INSERT Client
 FROM 'c:\MAIN SHARE\IMPORT TEST.csv'
 WITH
  (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   KEEPNULLS
   )
GO
-- COMMIT TRAN SAJ
--ROLLBACK TRAN SAJ

Comment: You BULK INSERT uses CR/LF as a row terminator. Therefore your "embedded" CR/LF will be interpolated as row terminators also, unless they can be somehow different. Since your row terminator is most likely of the form `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`, you'll need to replace either them or your embedded CR/LF's with something uniquely different, in your .csv file. The html `<br>` tag might be a good choice.

Comment: Yes many thanks for your help. I have done this in my csv (in Excel) and all is ok now :- =SUBSTITUTE(S2,CHAR(10),CHAR(13)&CHAR(10))

Comment: Actually scrap that, it isn't (and doesn't make sense what I said). I suppose my next question is how do I insert an HTML tag for all my CHAR(13)&CHAR(10) in Excel?